# Sum where respecting conditions group by

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Please how can i add a condition on my group by to say, if region == europe do the sum group by id, date. I mean by id and cat, we cant to know the distance in europe .

```
df['distance_europe'] = df.groupby(['id', 'date'])['distance'].transform('sum')
```

**data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['x2', 'x1', 'x1', 'x1'],
            'date':['2021-01-03','2021-01-02', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01'],
       'distance':[100, 200, 200, 100],
                'status': [0, 1, 2, 3],
               'region':['USA', 'EUROPE', 'EUROPE', 'EUROPE']})
```

**expected output**

```
df['distance_europe'] = [0, 200, 300, 300]
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of the input dataframe?

Comment: @Rishin i updated my original post! can you check please. ?

Comment: May I know the logic by which you got the expected output?  shouldn't the sum be 500?

Comment: because it is group by id and date. @Rishin where you see that it should be 500?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df['distance_europe'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.distance if x.region=='EUROPE' else 0, axis =1)
df['distance_europe'] = df.groupby(['id', 'date'])['distance_europe'].transform(sum)
df


    id  date       distance status  region  distance_europe
0   x2  2021-01-03  100       0      USA            0
1   x1  2021-01-02  200       1      EUROPE        200
2   x1  2021-01-01  200       2      EUROPE        300
3   x1  2021-01-01  100       3      EUROPE        300
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for set `distance` to `0` before `transform` with `sum`:

```
df['distance_europe'] = (df.assign(distance=df['distance'].where(df['region']=='EUROPE',0))
                           .groupby(['id', 'date'])['distance'].transform(sum))

print (df)
   id        date  distance  status  region  distance_europe
0  x2  2021-01-03       100       0     USA                0
1  x1  2021-01-02       200       1  EUROPE              200
2  x1  2021-01-01       200       2  EUROPE              300
3  x1  2021-01-01       100       3  EUROPE              300
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the `.groupby()` + `.transform()` based on a subset of `df` of `df.loc[df['region'] == 'EUROPE']` and then initialize `df['distance_europe']` for non-Europe rows to `0` , as follows:

```
df['distance_europe'] = df.loc[df['region'] == 'EUROPE'].groupby(['id', 'date'])['distance'].transform('sum')
df.loc[df['region'] != 'EUROPE', 'distance_europe'] = 0
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   id        date  distance  status  region  distance_europe
0  x2  2021-01-03       100       0     USA              0.0
1  x1  2021-01-02       200       1  EUROPE            200.0
2  x1  2021-01-01       200       2  EUROPE            300.0
3  x1  2021-01-01       100       3  EUROPE            300.0
```

With this code, you don't need to use `.apply()` on `axis=1` which is very slow and is considered better avoided.